# Simple email regex, make sure user includes dot domain?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I don't mess around with Regex too much but have been able to get this one online. `/.+@.+/`. This will return true with both `joe@joe` and `joe@joe.com`. I want to make it so a user must supply a domain extension otherwise I want it to fail, I presume this is quite simple but I just can't figure it out. I've tried `/.+@.+.\S/` but that didn't work. Any help would be great, thanks!

This will be used in both PHP and javascript. The current one works in both, the new will need to also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: From http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address `^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is expression

```
/\w+@\w+\.\w{2,10}/
```

to allow more characters:

```
/[\w\-\._]+@[\w\-\._]+\.\w{2,10}/
```

Comment: Thank you, nice and simple!

Comment: It's no longer incorrect now, but by using the `\w` category, you're excluding a lot of characters that are allowed in an email address.

Comment: Is there a way to allow those characters?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Elaborate?

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt It's simple: either you go for a correct regex (like the one in the accepted answer of the linked duplicated question), or you choose some trade-off. That trade-off is that you'll end up with a pattern that's either too wide or too narrow. If you're gonna go too wide, you might as well accept anything that is not a space: `\S+@\S+\.\S+`

Comment: Even using non-space is too narrow in some cases. `"Joe Blow"@joe.com` is a valid address.

Answer (score 1):

The regex here works for me (from http://www.regextester.com/19 )

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/i
```

As does this example of regex inside JavaScript from plnkr here: http://embed.plnkr.co/ZlbA1I2TsDBUmDb9o0gj/

Answer (score 0):

Given that I don't know what the rest of your code is and you might really need this for both `PHP` and `JavaScript` I will suggest a different approach as I don't agree with the solution given in the accepted answer because it will match email addresses like `-@-.aa`, `.@.-.aa`, `.@_.aa` etc.

I'd suggest you use PHP's [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var) with the [FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) filter which

> validates e-mail addresses against the syntax in RFC 822, with the exceptions that comments and whitespace folding and dotless domain names are not supported.

and probably an additional `AJAX` call from `JavaScript` .

Regular Expressions matching all valid email address are not trivial at all and I'm not even sure you can rely on them for matching **ALL** valid email addresses.

For more information please take a look at [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript) and [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score -1):

`.+\@.+\.{1}.+`

This is a simple regex and will match the required criteria

Comment: I've used them and it's extremely complex. I'm looking for something quite simple and short. I don't want a 200+ character regex.

Comment: No need to escape the `@`

Comment: @Mayur So you say `something              @ something .   .    .   com` is a valid email address?

Answer (score -1):

For a simple regex that will accept any domain extension of one character or longer, try: `/.+@.+\..+/`

For a 2 character domain extension or longer, try: `/.+@.+\..{2,}/`

Comment: That still matches on `joe@joe`

Comment: If you test it on this site, you will see that it does not, in fact match that. https://regex101.com/

Comment: That is where I'm testing. `/.+@.+..+/` matches `joe@joe`.

Comment: Oh, I see one of the delimeters got stripped from my copy paste. Let me update my answer.